# firestore.instance.runtransaction((transaction) async doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I tried to make application from this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase

and I got stuck at step 11 because

`Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async` won't work.

What should i do?

This is the code that i've made so far :

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {

    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

    return Padding(
        key: ValueKey(record.name),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
        child: ListTile(
            title: Text(record.name),
            trailing: Text(record.votes.toString()),
        onTap: () {
            print("123");
            Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                print("456");
                final freshSnapshot = await 
                transaction.get(record.reference);
                final fresh = Record.fromSnapshot(freshSnapshot);

                final Map<String, dynamic> json = HashMap<String, dynamic>();
                json['name'] = fresh.name;
                json['votes'] = fresh.votes + 1;
                print(fresh.name);

                await transaction.update(record.reference, json);
            });
        },
        ),
        ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show the code you have done so far? What errors are you getting?

Comment: it won't execute print("456");

Comment: What happens if you add `return` before `Firestore.instance.runTransaction((...` ? What caught my eye from their example is that they use `() => Firestore.....` contrary to your approach. Why have you changed that? Is that because you have added the print statements? :)

Comment: yes, i already tried their approach, but Firestore.instance.runTransaction((... ain't work, so i wonder is it the problem is the onTap, that's why i changed to () { .. and test it with print('123'). The print('123') work fine but it still not execute print('456')